404 error on hosting vite project on vercel on the main path. How to fix the issue?
I am trying to make a vite project and host it on vercel as two seperate deployments, one is frontend and the other is the server. The server side works fine but the frontend side is giving the issues. The site one loading shows the default 404 page of vercel and I am unable to resolve it. I hav tired everything I got to know but it did not work. The only time The project got hosted successfully was when I placed the vercel.json file on the base/root folder of the project outside frontend and server.
The code
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "server/api/server.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    },
    {
      "src": "frontend/dist/**",
      "use": "@vercel/static"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    { 
      "src": "/api/(.*)",
      "dest": "server/api/server.js"
    },
    { 
       "src": "/(.*)", 
       "dest": "frontend/dist/$1"
    }
  ]
}

But different page navigation did not work here. How should the code of frontend/vercel.json be like for the site to work.
Current Version of frontend/verson.json
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "dist/**",
      "use": "@vercel/static"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "dist/$1"
    }
  ]
}

My frontend/src/App.jsx file code
import { SpeedInsights } from "@vercel/speed-insights/next"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Form from './pages/Form';

import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard';
import ErrorPage from './pages/ErrorPage';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <SpeedInsights/>  
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/form" element={<Form />} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path="/error/:errorCode" element={<ErrorPage />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;

I am trying to fix the issue of page hosting and child navigation on vercel hosting.
